# How to hide country in Address Field display?

Tags: 7, entities

Using Drupal 7 with [Address Field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module.  How to prevent the country part of the address field from displaying on a node with an address field?

For example, address is:

```
123 Main St
Somewhere, NY 10001
United States
```

I want the node to show:

```
123 Main St
Somewhere, NY 10001
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I overrode the field.tpl.php file as described in this video:

[Drupal 7: Theming Fields and Nodes with Templates](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxZQqgvJk3s) by linwclark

I copied the field.tpl.php file from `<site_root>/modules/field/theme/field.tpl.php` and put it into the templates directory of my zen subtheme (`<site_root>/sites/all/themes/somezentheme/templates/field--field_address.tpl.php`)

In that template I used the hide() function on country:

```
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
    <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php hide($item['country']); print render($item); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [hook_field_formatter_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7) to display it as you need.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score -2):

you could also hide it with css. I use [css_injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) module to just insert the css on the page(s) where you want to hide the element.